React generate images instead of importing it after running build command
I have images stored in src/assets/images
and it works very fine in debug mode
But when i run npm run build react generates a new images (which mean imgs src  will be like data/...)
Instead of importing it from its original folder
And this what i'm expecting to get
<img src="images/example.png" alt="Hello">

This what  i got
<img src="data:image/..." alt="Hello">

